# Help me find some articles about the social engineering behind Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, blog

I remember seeing some old post (or a few) about how Stack Overflow was socially engineered. You know, the "special sauce" that makes it so good.

Can you help me find these?

Comment: We got skies to take down the mountain?

Comment: [Social engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_%28security%29) doesn't seem like the term you want to apply to what you're looking for. Manipulating people into doing things without their explicit consent doesn't seem like *A Good Thing*.

Comment: @Mark - perhaps there's a better term. I'm talking about the entire incentive system built into Stack Overflow to encourage people do good. I think it is social engineering, just not in a bad way (the Force has a light side as well).

Answer (score 3):

Start here: [Choosing your own adventure](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/choosing-your-own-adventure.html)

When you're done with CH, start again [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/page/2/).

That's a *lot* of blog-posts + podcasts to chew through, but it should give you a pretty good idea of why and how SO came into being the way it did. However, if you get through all of *that* and still need more... [There are twenty-two thousand Meta threads for you to read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions)

Comment: ... but don't worry, only a thousand or two of those are actually *relevant*

Comment: ... and which ones *those* are is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: ... and just when you think you're done, you pass 10K rep and have a few thousand more.